# If else not working, not entering the first condition

Tags: php

Can you please help me weather there is any thing wrong in the script it is not entering in if even if  "the if condition" is true,

I have added the complete code please check

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {
$client_name = $_POST['client_name'];
$other_client = $_POST['other_client'];
$district = $_POST['district'];
$taluka = $_POST['taluka'];
$village = $_POST['village'];
$mobile_no = $_POST['mobile_no'];
$case_no = $_POST['case_no'];
$sr_no = $_POST['sr_no'];



$sql3="SELECT total_amt from date where paydate  ='". $payment_date. "'";
$q = $pdo->prepare($sql3);
$q->execute(array($client_id));
$data = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);                                            

$dataamt = $data['total_amt'];                                          
$datadate = $data['paydate'];                                           

$newamt = $dataamt + $fees ;


if ( $datadate == $payment_date ) {

    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql12 = "UPDATE date set total_amt = ? where paydate = ?";
    $q12 = $pdo->prepare($sql12);
    $q12->execute(array($newamt,$payment_date));


} else {

    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql13 = "INSERT INTO date(paydate,total_amt) values(?,?)";
    $q13 = $pdo->prepare($sql13);
    $q13->execute(array($payment_date,$fees));


}
```

Comment: How can we tell without knowing the values of `$payment_date` and `$datadate`

Comment: First check to make sure the query works using your paydate value in your DB.

Comment: both are having dates, $payment_date is contaning the value posted from  date picker and $datadate is the date from database

Comment: @stomo21 if i remove if else its updating the value, but i wanted to add new entry if its not there

Comment: Your logic is wrong; this will lead to warnings when there are no matched records. Instead you need to check if a row was found. However, based on what you have shown, a `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`  would be a lot easier. Assuming that `paydate` is unique of course but your code would not make sense otherwise.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see you obtain any value from the $_POST to $payment_date ... ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
use strtotime() function

eg: 
$payment_date = strtotime($payment_date);
$datadate = strtotime($datadate);

if ( $datadate == $payment_date ) {
}
```

if you don't know about strtotime function use below link

http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_strtotime.asp

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you are using `$data['paydate']` but you are not selecting that column in your query, so that value does not exist in the result set.

```
$sql3="SELECT total_amt from date where paydate  ='". $payment_date. "'";
              ^^^^^^^^^ You are only selecting this value
...
// You are not selecting paydate in your query so this only generates a warning
// and the resulting value will be null
$datadate = $data['paydate'];

if ( $datadate == $payment_date ) {
```

Note that you should probably be using a prepared statement here as well.

Apart from that, when a row is found, these values will always match. It would be more logical to check if a row exists.

```
if ($q->rowCount() === 1)
```

However, based on what you have shown, an [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) would be a lot easier; only 1 query and no conditions. Assuming that paydate is unique of course but your code would not make sense otherwise.